# Model equation for customer numbers.

Tags: calculus, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to formulate an equation to determine the number of customers signed up to a subscription as a function of time. It's been 10 years since I studied maths, so bear with me!

The assumptions are:
Customers will join at a constant rate.
Customers will leave at a rate directly proportional to the number of customers currently subscribed. i.e. there when there are 200 customers, customers will be leaving at a rate double that of when there were 100 customers.

How do I write a function to describe this?
What is it called when the rate of change is dependent on a dependent variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is called a first-order differential equation. Let $y(t)$ be the number of customers at time $t$. Your conditions are that the rate of change of $y$, which is the derivative $y'$, is given by $y' = r - qy$, where $r$ is the number of customers that join and $q$ is the ratio of your current customers who leave in a unit of time. The solution to this equation is $y(t) = \frac{r}{q} - Ae^{-qt}$ for some constant $A$, which can be determined by the amount of customers at time $0$.

I.e., your number of customers will converge towards $r/q$ as time goes by, however many customers you start with.

Comment: I've tried playing with your equation, but I've run into some problems:
As I understand it, larger q means customers leave at a faster rate, where q=0 means customers never leave. However as q aproaches 0, r/q approaches infinite which clearly doesn't make sense.

Comment: Differential equations are like that. A solution will hold for most values of a fixed parameter, but for certain singular values (in this case $q = 0$, they cease to hold, and a different solution is needed. Fortunately that differential equation, $y' = r$ is easy: $y(t) = rt + C$ for some constant $C$, which is the number of customers you have at time 0.